# Java Server producing inconsistent output

Tags: java, multithreading, server, host, socketserver

I want to integrate a server with multiple clients for a blackjack game I created, and thus I began practicing with servers in java.  I create a thread, that when ran, forces the server to listen for input and produce an output.  Then I added a feature to stop the server.  However, the server randomly produces the correct output, and sometimes fails to connect.  Here is the code for when the user hosts a server:

```
st = new ServerThread();  //this is a field of type ServerThread
st.start();  //this runs the server concurrently as a new thread
```

Here is the code for when they close a server:

```
st.stopThread();
```

Finally, here is the source for the serverThread:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

private volatile boolean isRunning = true;
private Socket socket;
private static final int PORTNUM = 1342;

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {  //should run only when the
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORTNUM);  //uses the same port number, which I made a constant
            //Reading the an object of type Information from the client
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            Information i = (Information) serverInputStream.readObject();
            //arbitrarily changes the data stored in the information object to verify connection with server
            i.setI(100);
            i.setS("new string");
            i.setD(4.4);
            //sends the modified object back to the client
            serverOutputStream.writeObject(i);
            serverInputStream.close();
            serverOutputStream.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //System.out.println("IOException");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            //System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (socket != null) {  //avoid null pointer if no connections have been established
                    socket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}

public void stopThread() {
    isRunning = false;
}
```

}

Any suggestions on edits to make my code perform correctly and consistently would be welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be creating your ServerSocket *before* the while loop?

Comment: I took your advice and moved the initialization of the server socket to outside of the while loop.  However, the server is returning inconsistent (sometimes it outputs the correct data, and sometimes it won't connect)

Comment: what are you expecting as output and what are you actually seeing as output?

Comment: While the server is available (meaning I have hit host and haven't yet hit the close server button) I expect that when I connect to the server I receive the modified object i as feedback from the server.  However, my connection often throws IOExceptions.  Also, after I have closed the server (by interrupting the thread and changing the volatile field) it still returns the input (even though it should not take any more connections)  Whether it returns the correct input seems to be arbitrary and independent of whether or not I "closed" the server.

Comment: If you are getting `IOExceptions` you should post the entire stack trace in your question. Your code doesn't (and can't) check `isRunning` continuously, only at the top of the accept loop, so of course you're getting I/O done after you clear it.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the `socket` definition away from being an instance variable i.e,

```
while (isRunning) { 
  Socket socket = null;
  try {
  ...
```